# How to view WIFI devices names and signal strength

Tags: security, wifi, logs, python

I want a cli utility or script that shows all the Wifi devices or hotspots or access points and their signal strength.

I want to log this data using Python. I will write the logging script myself. But I'd prefer it if the CLI utility were a python script so that I can modify it.

Comment: `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan` did it for me.